# Display top 5 frequently purchased products - Open cart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to display top 5 frequently purchased items in Opencart product page.

Based on your feedback so far I just tried getting details using following SQL query:

```sql
select Distinct oc_order.order_id, oc_order.customer_id, oc_order_product.order_id,    oc_order_product.product_id, oc_order_product.name, oc_order_product.quantity 
from oc_order, oc_order_product 
where oc_order.order_id = oc_order_product.order_id
```

but I need complete idea so that I can develop code for it.

I've found this SQL query

```sql
SELECT oc_order_product.product_id, oc_order_product.customer_id, oc_order_product.name, SUM(oc_order_product.quantity) AS TotalQuantity
FROM oc_order_product
GROUP BY oc_order_product.product_id
ORDER BY SUM(oc_order_product.quantity) DESC LIMIT 5;
```

but I want to show only frequently purchased items for logged in user.

Comment: do you have a count of the number of purchases?

Comment: yes,
Table 
oc_order_product : order_product_id, order_id, product_id, name, quantity

Comment: Use Best Seller Module